# Contentment or Satisfaction, which is mostly in use?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

Please have a look at the below Google Ngram image,

I like to use **Contentment** in my sentences, but the image shows that the word **Contentment** has the least usage now a days.

So please help, is the word **Contentment** still in usage or I have to use the common word satisfaction always?

Advance thanks for your help.

Sorry for my bad English. English is not my native language.
[image]

Comment: Google Ngram only analyzes the occurrence of a word in literary materials, like books and articles, within a time frame selected by the user. That doesn't mean that the frequency of usage of '_contentment_' has been reduced. There are instances where '_content_' is the apt word to use, irrespective of potential alternatives. In those cases, substituting it with another word may not be the best thing to do.

Comment: [Related from EL&U Meta: Should we allow NGrams to be presented as statistical evidence](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/should-we-allow-google-ngrams-to-be-presented-as-statistical-evidence-without-qu).

Comment: "I like to use Contentment in my sentences". What sentences? You should add some examples which would help in discussing what words are appropriate. ngrams don't help because they cannot understand context using a single word.

Comment: @user3169, I usually comment and post about my feelings of serving humanity. Example: **There is nothing but satisfaction we get from making others happy**. I don't know but the word **Satisfaction** seems to me a very common word and has less value than the word **Contentment**. May be I am wrong. Please clarify. Sorry for my bad English if there is any mistake above.

Comment: Well, definitely **Satisfaction** is a more common word in general but let's not forget that there are situations where it's wiser to you another word like **Contentment** for instance or **Delight**, or **Pleasure**. Take this sentence, "**It is a pleasure to meet you**" - no other word will fit.

Comment: @SovereignSun, Is it ok to use the word Contentment in this sentence **There is nothing but satisfaction we get from making others happy**

Comment: @Raj33 Where've you seen that?

Comment: @SovereignSun , I made it myself. Is it grammatically wrong? or any better way to say this?

Comment: @Raj33 I wouldn't use the word "*Contentment*" in this context. I would use **pleasure** instead. Or I would rephrase it depending on the idea you imbue the phrase with.

Comment: @SovereignSun Could you please suggest me a better way to tell that sentence? It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems to me that the only questions you truly asked were whether *contentment* is still used and whether *you* can use it. The answer to both questions is a resounding "yes."

It may have slightly different connotations, as Canadian Yankee suggested. It may not be used as often—as both ngrams suggest. But it is a perfectly normal and acceptable word that is most *definitely* still in usage!

To steal an example from your question in the comments, these are both normal and have similar meanings:

> I get satisfaction from helping others.
> I find contentment in helping others.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that **contentment** and **satisfaction** are not exact synonyms.  **Contentment** is more specific than **satisfaction** and it evokes a mood of calm, stillness, or peace.  Wikipedia [defines contentment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contentment) as "...a mental or emotional state of satisfaction maybe drawn from being at ease in one's situation, body and mind."  This is why **satisfaction** is more common - it has a much broader meaning than **contentment** does.

I achieve **satisfaction** from a job well done, but find **contentment** in a quiet Sunday afternoon at home with no chores to do.

Answer (score -1):

By reducing the time frame shown on the Ngram to "our lifetimes" we can get a better comparison of word frequency.

As the comment stated, this is indeed based "only" on data from books and magazines.  However, we can see that the difference is significant: `satisfaction` is consistently used **over *10 times as often*** as `contentment`.

Literature and spoken words aren't out-of-sync by tenfold, so **I will say with** **100% confidence** that **`SATISFACTION` is used more often**, in all manners of English communication, including between the major regions.  (My own experience also agrees with that fact.)

*Can't argue with data.*

[image: Ngram]

---

[A modified Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contentment%2Csatisfaction%2Cpleasure%2Cdelight%2Cgratification%2Ctriumph&year_start=1975&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), Perhaps a better example, with all your sample words.  Those lines are pretty darn straight (ie., no fluctation) and that's a pretty huge gap between the 2 words in question.

If we were comparing the words `content` versus `happy`, [the results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=satisifed%2C%20happy%2C%20content&year_start=1975&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) would be **very** different.  `Content` is used 10000x more often than `Happy`...  but `content` has multiple meanings, one used much more often during our tech age (*"web site content"*, etc).

Comment: I agree **Satisfaction** is more common than **Contentment**. But I want to know which word would be more formal in writing?